# Strange search issue occuring after adding field as Alternate search key

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

I've added an alternate search key to our Vendor pages in FSCM. The search record for the page's component uses a SQL view that I modified, and added in the below custom (PS designated custom field) field (VNDR_FIELD_C30_B) into the view, as well as an additional field in the field list. On the Record Field's properties I set it as an Alternate Search Key.

[image]

This field now properly displays on my search page (I changed the label on it for be Employee ID) and I can properly search for a Vendor by inputting a SETID value, along with a value in the custom field. It will bring up the record appropriately, as shown below:

[image]

[image]

If I click the Return to Search button though, I am brought back to the search page as expected, however if I search for that same vendor again, (or any vendor for that matter) I am only brought to this partially loaded page, and all the other tabs you saw above for the Vendor are missing, as well as the typical bottom navigation/page functions.

[image]

I have to click on the page name again from the Breadcrumbs to refresh the page and then I can search for the vendor 1 time again, but on 2nd search I will encounter the same issue again.

Is there a reason this could be caused? Let me know if additional information is needed.

Comment: You have possibly been transferred to a different component that uses the same search record. CTRL+SHIFT+J on both pages to check if the component is different.

Comment: Peter I checked and it is the same component that uses the search record. Any other ideas?

Comment: I actually just looked in our production environment (where no changes have been made yet) and the same issue occurs there! It's looking like an actual PS bug, and nothing related to the change I made.

Comment: Look at the search record on the menu as well, but it does looks like a bug

Comment: Yes I see it was reported to Oracle as a bug, thanks.